# executable file with cx_freeze (PyQt5) crash on windows

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I programmed some GUI with PyQt5 and want to make it executable with cx_freeze. But I get some error message if I want to launch the programm. Following are my code and error message.

I installed Python 64-bit and also PyQt5 64-bit. If start

```
python hello.py
```

the program works fine.

Hope someone could help me, thank you in advance.

### setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
  includes = ['atexit','re']
  setup(
      name = 'programm',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'PyQt',
      options = {'build_exe' : {'includes' : includes }},
      executables = [Executable('hello.py', base = base)])
```

### hello.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
dialog.resize(QtCore.QSize(200,200))
dialog.setVisible(True)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I build the .exe with

```
python setup.py build
```

If I start the .exe I got:

> ... File "c:\python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in
>   _load_backward_compatible AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fix_up_module'

### EDIT:

What is wondering me, why this path `'c:\python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py'` occur. Because this path doesn not exist.

Comment: That's a known bug with cx_Freeze on Python 3.4.1. Download it from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) and install again, and it should be fixed.